# Applying correction value to shapefile due to older handheld GPS error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, coordinates, gps

I didn't realise that a limitation of an older handheld GPS may be that it would always be off target. After uploading polygon coordinates for a number of areas, I realised that the polygons were consistently off.

I can manually move on polygon based on visual queues on the topographic map using the digitise toolbar, but is it possible to apply this exact some shift to the other polygons in the shape file (as it is more difficult to use visual queues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** Have a look at the ["Affine transform"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#affine-transform) tool in the Processing Toolbox (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). It gives the most options for fine adjustment e.g. if you need to apply a rotation to each feature etc.

**Option 2:** For a manual *'by eye'* solution, select all features then use the Move Features tool from the [Advanced Digitizing Toolbar](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/documentation_guidelines/substitutions.html#digitizing-and-advanced-digitizing). By using a feature which you are able to manually correct using visual cues and dragging it around, all other selected features will move as a group (see gif below).

[image]